# Consider the terms with base five with non-negative powers:$5^0, 5^1, 5^2, ……$,prove there are two of these terms which differ by a multiple of 2021.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

Consider the terms with base five with non-negative powers:

$5^0, 5^1, 5^2, ……$

Prove using the pigeonhole principle that there are two of these terms which differ by a multiple of 2021.

So far from what i can tell we would consider the remainders of 2021 giving us n+r. r is the remainder when five divides 2021.

However, this solution has sort of reached a dead end for me and does not work. Im looking for an alternate solution to this.

Comment: You have finished the proof. How is it possible to be more efficient?

Comment: Hi Trebor, i said that i have reached a dead end meaning that my solution doesnt work. Sorry about the bad phrasing in my question

Comment: what does "...giving us $n+r$" mean?

Comment: Hi Misha, n+r would be n+ remainder when 5 divides 2021 but it doesnt seem to work. I will edit and specify this

Comment: How many possible remainders can you get when you divide $5^n$ by $2021$?

Comment: In your statement of the problem, I think it should rather be: "...there are at least two of these terms..." and also "However, this approach ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the set $\{ 5^n: n\in \{1,...,2022\} \}$, by the pigeonhole principle, there exist $m,n\in \{1,...,2022\}$ such that $5^n\equiv 5^m \ (\text{mod} \ 2021)$ and then $5^m-5^n$ is a multiple of 2021.